# Django get display name choices

Tags: python, django, templates

I'm trying to find a solution to my problem.

models.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField()

def archive_quality(self):
    return self.archive_set.order_by('-quality').distinct().values_list('quality', flat=True)


class Archive(models.Model):
    CHOICES_QUALITY = (
        ('1', 'HD YB'),
        ('2', 'HD BJ'),
        ('3', 'HD POQD'),
        ('4', 'HD ANBC'),
    )
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    quality = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=CHOICES_QUALITY)
```

arhives.html

```
{% for article in articles %}
    {{ article }}
    {% for quality in article.archive_quality %}
        {{ quality.get_quality_display }}#This is not working
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Update**
The function archive_quality is important, because it prevents recurrence in the template objects.

```
Example:
article:
   My article one
Archive:
       quality: 1111222333 >> without the function
       quality: 123 >> with function
```

Comment: can you complete your models.py. Your forloop missed the variable from the model

Comment: @catherine Sure, just add the full model.

Comment: Are all the choices really `'1'`?

Comment: @Koterpillar sorry fix now.

Answer (score 11):

**Option #1:**

models.py

```
CHOICES_QUALITY = (
    ('1', 'HD YB'),
    ('2', 'HD BJ'),
    ('3', 'HD POQD'),
    ('4', 'HD ANBC'),
)

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField()

    def archive_quality(self):
        quality = self.archive_set.order_by('-quality').distinct().values_list(
            'quality', flat=True)
        lists = []
        for q in quality:
            for choice in CHOICES_QUALITY:
                if choice[0] == q:
                    lists.append({'quality': choice[1]})
        return lists

class Archive(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    quality = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=CHOICES_QUALITY)
```

template

```
{% for article in articles %}
    {% for item in article.archive_quality %}
        {{ item.quality }},
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Option #2:**

archive_tag.py

```
from django import template
from app_name.models import CHOICES_QUALITY

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def quality(q):
    for choice in CHOICES_QUALITY:
        if choice[0] == q:
            return choice[1]
    return ''
```

template

```
{% load archive_tag %}

{% for article in articles %}
    {% for item in article.archive_quality %}
        {{ item|quality }},
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: wow thanks all work find. You can use forloop.last to see if there is a second object. Thanks for helping.

Comment: return dict(CHOICES_QUALITY).get(q) is shorter

Answer (score 9):

Try:   `get_quality_display()`

ref: [django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32561004)