# show forms data in human readable format django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

models.py

```
 PERSON_ACTIONS = (
        ('1', '01.Allowed to rest and returned to class'),
        ('2', '02.Contacted parents /guardians'),
        ('3', '02a.- Unable to Contact'),
        ('4', '02b.Unavailable - left message'))

class Actions(models.Model):    
    reportperson = models.ForeignKey(ReportPerson)
    action =  models.IntegerField('Action type', choices=PERSON_ACTIONS)
```

forms.py

```
class PersonActionsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    action = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Actions
        fields = ['action']
```

template

```
{{actionform.get_action_display}}
```

This is not showing the form data in human readable format.It is not rendering the integer value from db also.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984130/django-get-display-name-choices

Comment: @DominicRodger,not showing any data.

Comment: The example which given is with charField in models,i am using integerField and multichoiceField in form.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want that:

```
class PersonActionsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Actions
        fields = ('action',)
        widgets = {
            'action': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        }
```

See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields)

Comment: Sorry lalo,I am saving the form instance in db as integer and i am looking for showing the data in human redable format.

Comment: Why you dont use CharField?

Comment: As we are maintaning  the choice in form, in view coded to save in int.char field is not used.

Answer (score 0):

[Model.get_FOO_display()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display)?

In case you wan't to render value from instance in form:

```
{{actionform.instance.get_action_display}}
```

Comment: draganHR,it is displaying as None even if the values are their in form.